# regex: Reuse matched result to get another match of the same output?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a command that returns an output:

```
$ show
file 1  banana
file 3  apple
file 2  watermelon
file 0  tomato

file name 0=abc 1=def
          2=ghi 3=jkl
```

With a given file name, I would like to find the associated word. For example, `ghi` would match `watermelon`.

I am able to match the file number with `sed` and reuse the result:

```
$ filenum=$(show | sed -n 's/.*\<\([0-9]*\)=ghi\>.*/\1/p')
$ show | sed -n 's/file '"$filenum"'  \([a-z]*\)/\1/p'
watermelon
```

The output of `show` can be very long to compute, so I would like to avoid calling it twice. It is also possible to store the output in a variable and doing the same thing:

```
$ out=$(show)
$ filenum=$(echo "$out" | sed -n 's/.*\<\([0-9]*\)=ghi\>.*/\1/p')
$ echo "$out" | sed -n 's/file '"$filenum"'  \([a-z]*\)/\1/p'
watermelon
```

But I would like to do it with the minimal number of commands.

Is it possible to achieve the same result with only one call to `sed`, `awk`, or any similar utility?

***EDIT*** I would like a command `magic-command` that for a given file name, prints the associated word in the output of the `show` command. For example:

```
$ show | magic-command "ghi"
watermelon
$ show | magic-command "abc"
tomato
$ show | magic-command "def"
banana
```

The format of the `show` command is the following:

```
file <filenum>  <word>
...

file name <filenum>=<filename> ...
```

***EDIT 2***
Thanks for the answers, I never used `awk` before so I learned a lot thanks to you! So I tinkered them and ended up with the following:

```
$ cat magic-command.sh
#!/bin/sh
awk '
# Match the `<filenum>=<filename>` using the given <filename>
# to find to <filenum>
match($0, /([0-9]*)='"$1"'/, out ) {
  filenum=out[1]
}
# Fill n2name using the `file <filenume>  <word>` lines
/\<file [0-9]*\>/ {
  n2name[$2]=$3
}
END {
  print n2name[filenum]
}'
```

And then:

```
$ show | ./magic-command.sh "ghi"
watermelon
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, is this `file name 0=abc 1=def 2=ghi 3=jkl` is a shell variable? could you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! `file name 0=abc 1=def 2=ghi 3=jkl` is part of the output of the `show` command. Everything except the first line in the first block of code is the output of `show`.

Comment: please let me know if given solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/=/ {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( split($i,f,/=/) == 2 ) {
            name2nr[f[2]] = f[1]
        }
    }
    next
}
{ nr2text[$2] = $3 }
END { print nr2text[name2nr[name]] }
```

Using `cat file` (where `file` contains the output of `show` as provided in your question) in place of `show`:

```
$ cat file | awk -v name='ghi' -f tst.awk
watermelon
```

The above (and the other currently posted answer and any other obvious solution) will fail if a file name can contain `=` or spaces. If that can happen then you need to tell us how to identify file names as opposed to fields and/or assignment statements.

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you very much for your answer, it is interesting! No, `<filename>` will not contain any `=` or spaces. I am sorry some information was missing in my question: the only lines containing `=` are the `<filenum>=<filename>` ones but there is also much more different lines than the `file <filenum>  <word>` ones (but they don't begin by `file`). So for the second to last block, I would put `/^file/` as pattern.

Comment: As you can see if you read my answer, it doesn't rely on lines starting with `file` or anything else. I'd expect it'd work for you as-is - did you try it? If your posted sample input doesn't adequately represent your real input files then, obviously, fix it so we're not guessing at what the input might be and how to best handle it.

Comment: Indeed your code work even without the `/file/` pattern but I was thinking that avoiding unnecessary assignment in `nr2text` is better! Because the output is much complex, I preferred to keep it simple. It is also why I didn't edit my sample and just add a comment to your answer, because otherwise it was exactly what I asked for!

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP, OP needs to run it along with another program then try following.

```
cat script.ksh
your_command | awk  -v command="$1" -F' +|=' '
/^file/ && !/^file name/{
  a[$2]=$NF
}
/^file name/{
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2){
    array[$i]=$(i+1)}
}
/^ +/{
  for(j=2;j<=NF;j+=2){
    array[$j]=$(j+1)}
}
END{
  for(i in array){
    if(array[i]==command){  print array[i],a[i]  }
}}'
```

Following will be the output when we run the script.

```
./script.ksh "ghi"
ghi watermelon
```

---

---

There are still lot of questions in your post which are not clear, totally based on what you have posted, try following once(based on completely shown as per your sample only).

```
awk -F' +|=' '
FNR==NR{
  if($0 ~ /file name/){
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2){
      array[$i]=$(i+1)
    }
    getline
    for(j=2;j<=NF;j+=2){
      array[$j]=$(j+1)
    }
  }
  next
}
($2 in array){
  print array[$2],$NF
}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
def banana
jkl apple
ghi watermelon
abc tomato
ghi jkl
```

Considering that your `show` function outputs into a `Input_file` here and I am reading Input_file 2 times here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it seems not possible to achieve what I want without pre-processing (here, putting the output of `show` in a separate file). Could you please tell me what are the things that are not clear in my post?

Comment: @anonom, you expected output and your conditions of getting it are NOT at all clear, please re-phrase your question again and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I not sure why you don't find my expected output explicit: I would like a `magic-command` that let me having this: `show | magic-command "ghi"` that returns `watermelon`. It is what it happens in the attempts I wrote. I will try to add another example but I don't see what is missing.

Comment: thanks for the new solution. As I am new to SO (less than 15 reputation) my votes are not displayed publicly. The expected output is not exactly the same, I think the last print should be just `print a[i]`. Otherwise, awesome! Thanks for your help. I need to compare the two answers I got before accepting one as the answer. I need to learn more about `awk`!

Comment: @anonom, not an issue we all are here to learn good that you up-vote to encourage people, you should select an answer as correct answer too out of all answers to close the thread completely. yes please share your feedback for answers which is important for all of us to learn.